# BankAccount.Comision does not contain a definition for 'comis'

Tags: c#, .net

I am following an online tutorial and I do exactly the same, but still, I am facing that error "BankAccount.Comision does not contain a definition for comis" you can find it in Withdraw() method.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using static BankingSystem.BankAccount;
    
    namespace BankingSystem

{
    class BankDetails : IBankDetails
    {
        ReturnedVal rv = new ReturnedVal();
        List<BankAccount> _accounts;

        public BankDetails()
        {
            _accounts = new List<BankAccount>();
        }

        public List<BankAccount> Account
        {
            get { return _accounts; }
        }


        public void CreateAccount(string name)
        {
            BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
            CalculateIBAN calculateIban = new CalculateIBAN();
            

            try
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                {
                    account.Name = name;
                    account.IBAN = calculateIban.IBAN();
                    _accounts.Add(account);
                    Console.WriteLine("Account created - Name: {0}, IBAN: {1}", account.Name, account.IBAN);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Account name is null or empty.");
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ne)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ne.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        public float Deposit()
        {
            string iban = rv.EnterIban();
            BankAccount account = rv.GetAccountByName(iban, _accounts);

            while (account == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Account doesn't exist");
                iban = rv.EnterIban();
                account = rv.GetAccountByName(iban, _accounts);
            }

            float sum = rv.AmountToDeposit();
            while (sum <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Amount cannot be less or equal than 0.");
                sum = 0;
                sum = rv.AmountToDeposit();
            }

            account.Sum += sum;
            Console.WriteLine("Added {0} to account {1}", sum, iban);

            return account.Sum;
        }

        public float Withdraw()
        {
            BankDetails details = new BankDetails();
            BankAccount.Comision c = Comision.comis;

            string iban = rv.EnterIban();
            BankAccount account = rv.GetAccountByName(iban, _accounts);

            while (account == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Account doesn't exist");
                iban = rv.EnterIban();
                account = rv.GetAccountByName(iban, _accounts);
            }

            float sum = rv.AmountToDeposit();
            while (sum <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Amount cannot be less or equal than 0.");
                sum = 0;
                sum = rv.AmountToDeposit();
            }

            account.Sum -= sum;

            Console.Write("Withdrawn {0} from account {1}.", sum, iban);
            Console.WriteLine("Comision {0}", Math.Round(c(account.Sum), 2));
            account.Sum -= c(account.Sum);
            Console.WriteLine("Remaining: {0}", Math.Round(account.Sum, 2));

            return account.Sum;
        }

        public float Balance()
        {
            string iban = rv.EnterIban();
            BankAccount account = rv.GetAccountByName(iban, _accounts);

            Console.WriteLine("IBAN: {0} has {1} left", iban, account.Sum);

            return account.Sum;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Class where I declared that delegate to calculate commission has some properties. Error occured at `BankAccount.Comision c = Comision.comis` withdraw() method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BankingSystem
{
    public class BankAccount
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string IBAN { get; set; }
        public float Sum { get; set; }

        public delegate float Comision(float comis);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare Comision? Update your question with its code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BankAccount.Comision is a delegate, you need to supply a method to it. See: [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-declare-instantiate-and-use-a-delegate)

Something like this:

```
// Declare it with lambda, it gets a float and returns the duplicated value of it
BankAccount.Comision c = value => 2 * value;

// Calls the delegate with the value 2.2 (It will return 4.4)
var comision = c(2.2f);
```

**EDIT:** You are already calling the method here (It's at the bottom of the withdraw method):

```
Console.WriteLine("Comision {0}", Math.Round(c(account.Sum), 2));
account.Sum -= c(account.Sum);
```

Comment: i am new to programming and this is my 2nd project, declaring it with lamba expression slove the problem but what is the purpose of 2nd line of code and where i called it?

Comment: The second line is just an example to show you how you can call the delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Bencel, can you please give me a favor, if you can edit that withdraw() method and tell me where i call that delegate?